# Android- How can I save a full photo with a custom name?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am saving a full size photo according to documentation.
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir("TestImageCapture");
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    String currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

According to my code it should save the image named: JPEG_20191012_.jpg but its saving JPEG_20191012_200766502860978687.jpg Why I'm getting this long number at the end. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
 File file = new File(storageDir.getAbsolutePath()+ imageFileName+ ".jpg");
   try {
          file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: its working but it starts with 2nd character "PEG_20191012_"

Comment: Please check properly  if you have added the proper file name

Comment: Please accept the answer and upvote it. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this method it will work not just by filename but also with date and time the image captured.

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss").format(new 
    Date());
    String imageFileName = "Service IN:" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```